# java.lang.StackOverflowError in pio train phase

Tags: java, debugging, apache-spark, docker, predictionio

`pio train` (after a successful `pio build`)  gives me an error like that:

```
[ERROR] [Executor] Exception in task 0.0 in stage 39.0 (TID 34)
[WARN] [TaskSetManager] Lost task 0.0 in stage 39.0 (TID 34, localhost): java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.peek(ObjectInputStream.java:2321)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peek(ObjectInputStream.java:2614)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2624)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1321)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:362)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1909)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
```

From here, the ObjectInputStreams etc. repeat more or less till the stack is full.

Does anyone have a hint what this might be or how to debug this?

**NB**: I'm running prediction.io inside a docker container which might (?) cause the problem, but again: I do not really know how to go on from there.

Any help is truly appreciated.

PS: I increased the stacksize using  `SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS="-Xss=9m"`with no effect, but I guess an infinite recursion is the culprit anyway.

Comment: which template are you using?

Comment: The [similarproduct](http://templates.prediction.io/PredictionIO/template-scala-parallel-similarproduct) template. What I didn't mention was, that a couple of weeks ago (when I last tried it) it worked fine. So _something_ changed.

Answer (score 2):

A similar error showed up in my case (also using a Docker container). I found two ways to resolve the problem.

#### Option 1: Increase Prediction IO's driver memory

Use the `--driver-memory` flag:

`pio train -- --driver-memory 2g`

From the [Tapster example](http://predictionio.incubator.apache.org/demo/tapster/):

> [Use] the --driver-memory option to limit the memory used by Apache PredictionIO (incubating). Without this Apache PredictionIO (incubating) can consume too much memory leading to a crash.

#### Option 2: increase JVM memory

This can be accomplished by calling `export JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx2g` before `pio train`.

See [What are the Xms and Xmx parameters when starting JVMs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvms) for more detail on the JVM's memory options.

Comment: I don't have the code at hand right now. But I find it interesting, that from the doc you quoted, `--driver-memory` _limits_ the memory usage. So (if the doc is right) the memory given to pio is reduced this way.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me. Is it possible that by using this flag, the algorithm limits its memory usage instead of increasing the reserved memory? But if I recall correctly, I reset the JVM memory to a value far less than 2GB, hence it seems that the allocated memory is also influenced. When I have some more time I'll try to get a bit deeper on this subject.

Comment: I tried ` pio train -- --driver-memory 4g --conf spark.executor.cores=1`, and successfully